# Setting number format for floats when writing dataframe to Excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a script producing multiple sheets for processing into a database but have strict number formats for certain columns in my dataframes.

I have created a sample dict for based on column headers and number format required and a sample df.

```
import pandas as pd

df_int_headers=['GrossRevenue', 'Realisation', 'NetRevenue']

df={'ID': [654398,456789],'GrossRevenue': [3.6069109,7.584326], 'Realisation': [1.5129510,3.2659478], 'NetRevenue': [2.0939599,4.3183782]}

df_formats = {'GrossRevenue': 3, 'Realisation': 6, 'NetRevenue': 4}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)

def formatter(header):
    for key, value in df_formats.items():
        for head in header:
            return header.round(value).astype(str).astype(float)
df[df_int_headers] = df[df_int_headers].apply(formatter)
df.to_excel('test.xlsx',index=False)
```

When using current code, all column number formats are returned as 3 .d.p. in my Excel sheet whereas I require different formats for each column.

Look forward to your replies.

Comment: Your code is not running, please provide a working example (and additionally how `df` looks like as text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working pass dictioanry to [`DataFrame.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html), for your original key-value `'NetRevenue': 4` are returned only `3` values, in my opinion there should be `0` in end which is removed, because number:

```
df={'ID': 654398,'GrossRevenue': 3.6069109, 
   'Realisation': 1.5129510, 'NetRevenue': 2.0939599}

df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=[0])

df_formats = {'GrossRevenue': 3, 'Realisation': 6, 'NetRevenue': 5}

df_int_headers = list(df_formats.keys())
df[df_int_headers] = df[df_int_headers].round(df_formats)
```

Comment: Tried with full dataset (100,000 rows, 144 columns) and output file is looking correct. Thanks for the help.